# Why does the requested popup not open?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

- I use this code in other .ts and it works, but not in this .ts
- I want to open this popup when the user clickOn the button, but when the user click, it doesn't do anything.
- In the .html i write this
  **<ngx-button (clicked)="openModalComprobante()" type="dark-green" text="Mostrar comprobante">**

````
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NbDialogService, NbStepperComponent } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NavigationService } from 'app/pages/user/services/navigation.service';
import { AlertsService } from 'app/services/alerts.service';
import { HeaderService } from 'app/services/header.service';
import { CardClienteCuentaCorriente } from 'app/shared/card-cliente-cta-cte/interfaces/card-cliente-cta-cte.interface';
import { Cliente } from 'app/utils/interfaces/cliente.interface';
import { PaymentMethodEnum, PaymentMethodTitleEnum } from 'app/utils/interfaces/payment-method.interface';
import { Payment } from 'app/utils/interfaces/payment.interface';
import { PaymentCacheService } from '../../services/payments/payment-cache.service';
import { SucursalesService } from '../../services/sucursales/sucursales.service';
import { paymentMethodsList } from '../cobrar-comanda/utils/payment-methods-list';
import { PopupComprobanteComponent } from '../popup-comprobante/popup-comprobante.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-cobrar-multiple-payment-methods',
  templateUrl: './cobrar-multiple-payment-methods.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cobrar-multiple-payment-methods.component.scss']
})
export class CobrarMultiplePaymentMethodsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() public: boolean;
  clienteCtaCte: CardClienteCuentaCorriente
  id;

openModalComprobante() {
     this.dialogService.open(PopupComprobanteComponent, {
       context: {
         comandaId: this.id ? this.id : this.data.id,
         public:this.public,
         cliente:this.clienteCtaCte
       }
     })
   }```
````

Comment: And you're sure that the function is called? if you add a ```console.log("click")``` in openModelComporbante().

Comment: how does this even compile without a constructor where you inject the dialogService?

Comment: @E.Maggini it has a constructor -->

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private comandaService: ComandaService,
    private clientesService: ClientesService,
    private headerService: HeaderService,
    private alerts: AlertsService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private navigationService: NavigationService,
    private router: Router,
    private modal: NbDialogService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private sucursalesService: SucursalesService,
    private dialogService: NbDialogService,
    private paymentsCache: PaymentCacheService
  ) { }

Comment: @CharlieV Yes, the function is called but it throws me this error
https://prnt.sc/bBMSJXF-TvyC

Comment: Is it possible that both this.id and this.data.id are undefined? Can you console.log() them to see what they are?